# Matlab: Differentiate between p and d

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, text

I am trying to write a script to automatically evalute a test (D2 Concentration Endurance Test)
An examplary image is shown here:

[image]

The goal is to cross all d's with to strikes: So you would have to cross all d's with 2 strikes below, 2 strikes above, 1 strike below and 1 strike above the letter.

So my main question is: **How can I automatically differentiate if the printed letter is a d or p?**
Is there a metric than I can apply to all letters, which differentiates the two letters? I tried entropy, but difference is not discernable using that metric.

I already tried OCR, but weirdly enough, ocr doesn't return any result for the letters I put in. And I think that ocr is maybe not necessary - I am only trying to differntiate between p's and d's - maybe an ocr is a bit overkill for this? This is why I thought a simple metric could be enough..

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: yes - I tried that, but weirdly enough, ocr doesn't return any result for the letters I put in.
And I think that ocr is maybe not necessary - I am only trying to differntiate between p's and d's - maybe an ocr is a bit overkill for this?
This is why I thought a simple metric could be enough..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get pretty good performance with picking a centroid which minimizes the Wasserstein (earth movers) distance. I downloaded some handwritten digits for 9's and 6's [here](http://cis.jhu.edu/~sachin/digit/digit.html) to test this out, and was able to get classification accuracy on the order of ~98-99% without a lot of effort. I picked the 9's and 6's because the rotational symmetry they have is analogous to the p's and d's in your problem.

In total I had 1000 images of a 6 and 1000 images of a 9, each 28 x 28 pixels. The pixel intensities are not binary, but performance is still good with binary pixels.

By using Wasserstein distance on images, you are viewing the observed pixel locations as realizations of a random distribution over the pixel grid. That is, for the numbers 6 and 9, there is a distribution over where pixels end up. Then, for each individual image, the obtained values can be viewed as the observed empirical sample from this distribution. This changes the problem from being viewed as "each image is a data point" to something more like "each observed pixel is a data point." Wasserstein distance is a metric on probability measures, so framing the images this way allows you to use a distance metric not immediately obviously intended for it.

The Wasserstein distance then calculates how much "mass needs to be moved" to turn one distribution into the other. This is complicated for non-atomic distributions, but for atomic distributions turns into solving a linear program, and a bunch of people have developed various softwares to do this. A good implementation of the Wasserstein distance in Matlab can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22962-the-earth-mover-s-distance).

This function takes 5 arguments and gives two values:

```
[x, fval] = emd(F1, F2, W1, W2, Func)
```

For our purposes F1 and F2 are the images (more on this later), and W1 and W2 are weights for the atoms. Because we're viewing the image as an unweighted empirical distribution, we can specify W1 and W2 to be a uniform weighting. Func is a function provided at the previous link. The important output is the real valued fval result, which gives the cost of moving the mass in F1 to F2. This is our "distance", and the thing we want to minimize in our classification.

Assuming you have some pre-classified images, come up with a "centroid" for the distributions by averaging over known 6's and 9's. Define these centroids as:

```
% Have "canonical example" from known images
6_centroid = mean(known_sixes,3);
9_centroid = mean(known_nines,3);
% Construct storage vectors for classifications
6_classify = zeros(1,num_testing);
9_classify = zeros(1,num_testing);
% Classify each image according to which centroid is closest in Wasserstein distance:
for j = 1:num_testing
% Compute the distance between each of the testing images for nines versus the centroid for 6's
       [flow6,cost_of_flow6]=emd(test_9(:,:,j),6_centroid,(1/28)*ones(1,28),(1/28)*ones(1,28),@gdf); 
    % Compute the distance between each of the testing images for nines versus the centroid for 9's
       [flow9,cost_of_flow9]=emd(test_9(:,:,j),9_centroid,(1/28)*ones(1,28),(1/28)*ones(1,28),@gdf); 
       % Classify based on minimizing Wasserstein Distance
       if cost_of_flow6<=cost_of_flow9
           nine_classify(j) = 6;
       else
           nine_classify(j) = 9;
       end
    % Compute the distance between each of the testing images for sixes versus the centroid for 6's
       [flow6,cost_of_flow6]=emd(test_6(:,:,j),6_centroid,(1/28)*ones(1,28),(1/28)*ones(1,28),@gdf); 
    % Compute the distance between each of the testing images for sixes versus the centroid for 9's
       [flow9,cost_of_flow9]=emd(test_6(:,:,j),9_centroid,(1/28)*ones(1,28),(1/28)*ones(1,28),@gdf); 
       % Classify based on minimizing Wasserstein Distance
       if cost_of_flow6<=cost_of_flow9
           six_classify(j) = 6;
       else
           six_classify(j) = 9;
       end
end
```

**Important** One important thing to note here that drastically affects performance is how you specify the rows and columns. The emd function does not view the images as distributions over pixels in the 2d space necessarily, but distributions over rows or columns, depending on the orientation of the image. For example, if you look at the rows of the image as being the samples, then for 6's and 9's (and likely p's and d's) the distributions is not going to be as well separated in earth movers distance because both 9's and 6's concentrate the majority of their mass towards the center of the horizontal axis.

However, if you look at the columns as samples, you can see that with 9s the distribution is heavily skewed towards the top, and 6's towards the bottom. Additionally, because the numbers are taller than they are wide, there is additional mass moving that must occur because the "stuff" has to travel a further distance. This makes it such that choosing the columns as the samples gives much better performance (98% accuracy versus 73%). This is all likely true of p's and d's as well.

Comment: Hey,
thank you very much for your help!! I seriously didn't expect so much input in one post.
I reimplemented your approach using the 6's and 9's - database. 
But I am not sure, how to implement your last comment. How do I change how rows and columns are specified? 
I do understand your point, but I am not sure, how I can translate that into code..

Comment: Just make sure the images are input in the function vertically oriented (don't transpose them).

Comment: Wow - now I also get Accuracys of 95%/98%.
I will generate a test set for d's and p's and test with them.
I will let you know how it's working out!!

Comment: You can get better classification accuracy than that using something like a NN for sure, but I if you want a method which uses some distance metric I think the EMD is pretty good.